# Semi-randomization of matrix

Tags: matlab, function, random, matrix

I created the matrix: A with random numbers 1-8, each element with 4 repetitions per row, A has 6rows, 32columns. I know there are more elegant ways to do this, but I am a matlab beginner, therefore I used the knowledge I have...

```
A1 = [1:8,1:8,1:8,1:8];
A1 = A1(randperm(length(A1)));
A2 = [1:8,1:8,1:8,1:8];
A2 = A2(randperm(length(A2)));
A3 = [1:8,1:8,1:8,1:8];
A3 = A3(randperm(length(A3)));
A4 = [1:8,1:8,1:8,1:8];
A4 = A4(randperm(length(A4)));
A5 = [1:8,1:8,1:8,1:8];
A5 = A5(randperm(length(A5)));
A6 = [1:8,1:8,1:8,1:8];
A6 = A6(randperm(length(A6)));
Aall(1,:)=A1;
Aall(2,:)=A2;
Aall(3,:)=A3;
Aall(4,:)=A4;
Aall(5,:)=A5;
Aall(6,:)=A6;
```

Now I want to make sure that the first element of each row in "Aall" is unequal to all the other first elements of the other rows(or: the first column of the matrix starts with a different number), using a function. I struggle with creating this function...any help is appreciated!and also consecutive repetitions of the same element in one row (e.g. 5 5) is not allowed. How do I implement that in one function?

Comment: You said - `"first element of each row is unequal to all the other ones"`. By other ones, do you mean other first elements of other rows or other elements in the same row?

Comment: I mean the first elements of the other rows, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I would propose this solution

```
for j=2:6
    while max(Aall(j,1)==Aall(1:j-1,1))
        z = randperm(size(Aall,2));
        Aall(j,:)=Aall(j,z);
    end;
end;
```

Here, we go from one element to other in the first column and compare it with all preceding elements. If a coincidence is found, elements of that row are rearranging till we get a value that differs from others.